# AWS Cognito for facebook users with serverless framework

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, serverless, amazon-cognito-facebook

I use [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) for AWS Serverless Application for creating REST Full API's.

**Requirement**

Any Users (e.g register, facebook, google) any devices (e.g Mobile or Web) use API that authenticates via JWT token. if the token is valid user can access **AWS Lambda** function via **AWS API Gateway**.

**What I do**

Use AWS Cognito User Pools for Register and Facebook users, for social user I use Identity providers for getting JWT token, that access API.
It's work perfectly fine.

**What I need**

For mobile users in social login, Facebook gives access token, using that token can I register or login in **AWS Cognito User Pools** not **AWS Cognito Federated Identities** ?, After login **AWS Cognito User Pools** gives JWT token for access **AWS lambda function using AWS API gateway.**

**Why I need**

Because of Serverless framework handle authorizer with JWT. [Link](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#http-endpoints-with-custom-authorizers)

Is it right flow?